# Which representation is used to show symmetry in SM Lagrangian

Tags: particle-physics, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, standard-model

Consider the whole Lagrangian of the SM.

Where are we using the defining representation and where are we using the adjoint representation of the three symmetry groups involved to show that the Lagrangian remains invariant?

More specifically, is it correct to say that when the electroweak section is transformed under $SU(2)$ the QCD section should be transformed using the trivial representation of $SU(3)$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for - the Standard Model has a list of fields, and each field transforms in a specific representation of each symmetry group. What are you asking when you ask "where" we use representations?

Comment: I mean is there a difference to use the defining representation of the groups or the adjoint representations? Are we free to choose whatever representation?

Comment: For which field are we using the adjoint representation?

Comment: You use the adjoint reps for the gauge fields of the factor groups and the fundamentals for the fermions and the Higgs doublet. Indeed, the product of the groups is Cartesian, so an EW trasnformation knows absolutely nothing about a strong color trasnformation.